# How to get Cloud Connector Menu at Wincc 7.4 Explorer

Tags: wincc

I am new in Siemens Wincc 7.4 Explorer. While when I used WinCC 7.5 there is a option to connect cloud server using MQTT client. While using WinCC 7.4, I am not able to found the option to connect to cloud. Is there is any way as how to get the Cloud Connect option at WinCC 7.4 Explorer.

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

As of WinCC V7.5, you can use the "WinCC Cloud Connector" to establish direct communication in the cloud (e.g. "Amazon AWS"). Communication with Siemens MindSphere and Microsoft Azure is possible from WinCC V7.5 SP1 only.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but no. You need some sort of a third party app like node-red or a special edge/cloud device.

Please remember to keep your system secure and hardened!

//PerD